# Comparing time in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

How can I comparte two time type variables in a function in the model?

Like:

```
first_hour -(minus) end_hour > 10 minutes
```

Actually, that exact operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
array('myDate', 'type', 'type' => 'date', 'message' => '{attribute}: is not a date!', 'format'=>'yyyy-M-d H:m:s')
```

Comment: But the variable is just time, no date u.u

Comment: @mtrx try 'format'=>'H:m:s' http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/reference-model-rules-validation/#hh8